# Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent Playwright detection

Tags: python, webdriver, playwright, playwright-python

Selenium can use execute_cdp_cmd() to prevent navigator.webdriver.

such as

```
chrome.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {
'source': 'Object.defineProperty(navigator,"webdriver",{get: () => undefined})'})
```

So Playwright what method should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [addInitScript](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-add-init-script) function.

```
await page. add_init_script("() => Object.defineProperty(navigator,'webdriver'...");
```

Comment: Thanks,I use python operate the playwright.
page.add_init_script() can do this

Comment: cool. I'll edit the answer and change the tags on your question :)